# Using JSON_QUERY as DbFunction in EF Core 6

Tags: json, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to utilize SQL Server's built in JSON functionality with Entity Framework Core 6. It actually works exceedingly well with JSON_VALUE as shown below.

```
var results = _context.Pages.Where(p => MyDbFunctions.JsonValue(p._PublishedContent, "$.content").ToLower().Contains("test"));
```

DbContext is as follows:

```
public class JsonValueTestingContext : DbContext
{
    public JsonValueTestingContext(DbContextOptions context) : base(context) { }
    public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MyDbFunctions.JsonValue(default(string), default(string)));
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MyDbFunctions.JsonQuery(default(string), default(string)));
    }
}

public static class MyDbFunctions
{
    [DbFunction("JSON_VALUE", Schema = "", IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static string JsonValue(string source, [NotParameterized] string path) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    [DbFunction("JSON_QUERY", Schema = "", IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static string JsonQuery(string source, [NotParameterized] string path) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

The challenge I'm running into is that JSON_VALUE is good for basic types like string, int, boolean, datetime, etc. However, I do also store a string of arrays like ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear'] and I would very much like to do something similar to the following:

```
var results = _context.Pages.Where(p => MyDbFunctions.JsonQuery(p._PublishedContent, "$.content").Contains("Apple"));
```

I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the latter. If I try to return a string[] type for JSON_QUERY in MyDbFunctions, it says it is an invalid return type for the provider. I've tried all sorts of casting too, and Linq cannot translate. I feel like there must be a way.

Comment: `JSON_QUERY` returns a `nvarchar(max)` so doesn't really make sense to do `Contains` anyway. Perhaps you want the table valued function [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead?

Comment: Thanks, with your suggestion I was able to solve it. I'll post the full solution as an answer for future visitors to this post.

Comment: Note by the way that `OPENJSON` has two versions: without a `WITH` schema or including one. Without one means you can break open arrays containing bare values such as strings or numbers into `[key], value, type` where `[key]` is the index. If you supply a schema then you can break open arrays containing objects, but you don't get the index. Supplying a `WITH` schema is going to be difficult in EF, and the fact the returned table is dynamic makes things worse also.

Comment: Yes, I went with the one without the `with`, just key and value only since it's just a raw string of arrays. I posted my answer now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to use OPENJSON, not JSON_QUERY in this scenario. On top of that there are some additional considerations. For example, you need to create a Keyless object with Key / Value attributes and specify IQueryable as the return type on the OPENJSON static method. See example below.

```
public class JsonValueTestingContext : DbContext
{
    public JsonValueTestingContext(DbContextOptions context) : base(context) { }
    public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MyDbFunctions.JsonValue(default(string), default(string)));
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MyDbFunctions.OpenJson(default(string), default(string)));
    }
}

public static class MyDbFunctions
{
    [DbFunction("JSON_VALUE", Schema = "", IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static string JsonValue(string source, [NotParameterized] string path) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    [DbFunction("OPENJSON", Schema = "", IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static IQueryable<ArrayDatabaseItem> OpenJson(string source, [NotParameterized] string path) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}

[Keyless]
public class ArrayDatabaseItem
{
    public int Key { get; set;  }
    public string Value { get; set;  }
}
```

And usage may look like:

```
var results = _context.Pages.Where(p => MyDbFunctions.OpenJson(p._PublishedContent, "$.array_item").Any(c => c.Value == "Choice 2"));
```

@Charlieface's comment and this part of [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-openjson-with-the-default-schema-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#example---return-each-element-of-an-array) helped me arrive at the answer.

Comment: You could add another property `int Type`. Also the path is optional (default is `$`)

Comment: You can also put link to [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-queryable-function-to-a-table-valued-function)